# How do I unit test rendering views in Express?

Tags: express, mocha.js, sinon, chai

my controller queries an API on another server I've already tested and it works correctly. I'm curious how I would go about testing this controller, all it does is fetch the api data and render it. I've already tested and verified that my api works with chai-http so how does one correctly unit test this?

```
function(req, res){ 
    rp(http://www.foobar.com/api/posts)
    .then(function(posts){
        res.render('view', { data : posts } );
     })
    .catch(function(err){
     next(err);
    })
}
```

Comment: It's good that you like to unit test, but the more important question is if it makes sense to unit test this. IMHO, the answer is no. There is no branching - except for the error handler. This is too simple to justify testing on any other level than from the outside, as in just using a browser.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's appreciated!

Comment: @oligofren This is subjective. I would not bother testing the view structure in full, but would perhaps assert that `{ data : posts }` is passed to the view. If there is some kind of iteration logic in the view for example, this could easily be tested here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Tape as opposed to mocha/chai, but my approach might help you.

I just assert that the response *includes* the text I am expecting.

```
test('Post /auth/login renders an error raised by the api service', (t) => {
  let spy = sinon.spy();
  let mock = sinon.stub(api, 'doLogin')
    .resolves({dataForView: 'great success'});

  request(app)
    .post('/auth/login')
    .expect(200)
    .end((err, res) => {
      t.ok(res.text.includes('great success'));
      t.end();

      mock.restore();
    });
});
```

The key part is the `t.ok(res.text.includes('great success'));`. I don't bother asserting that my entire view is rendered as expected, just that any data I am passing into the render call actually ends up in the response.

Comment: What do `spy` and `mock` do here. I only see that `mock` is `restore`'d at the end, but I don't really understand what is happening with those variables. Apologies, I am new to testing in Node.